# How to do a simple pattern coding

Tags: r

If I want to have the numbers coded like this, could you give me some suggestion about the codes?

```
1
2 3
6 5 4
7 8 9 10
15 14 13 12 11
...........
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

Another base R option

```
v <- choose((1:5) + 1, 2)
Map(function(x, y) {
  ifelse(x %% 2, rev, I)((y - x + 1):y)
}, seq_along(v), v)
```

gives

```
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 6 5 4

[[4]]
[1]  7  8  9 10

[[5]]
[1] 15 14 13 12 11
```

Comment: What is I doing here?

Comment: @AnilGoyal `I` means keeping the object as it is (type `?I` and see the manual). You can use `c` instead as well here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `split`

```
lst1 <- split(1:15, rep(1:5, 1:5))
lst1[c(TRUE, FALSE)] <- lapply(lst1[c(TRUE, FALSE)], rev)
```

-output

```
lst1
#$`1`
#[1] 1

#$`2`
#[1] 2 3

#$`3`
#[1] 6 5 4

#$`4`
#[1]  7  8  9 10

#$`5`
#[1] 15 14 13 12 11
```

---

Or another option is

```
m1 <- matrix(NA, 5, 5)
m1[upper.tri(m1, diag = TRUE)] <- 1:15
m1 <- t(m1)
m1[c(TRUE, FALSE),] <-  t(apply(m1[c(TRUE, FALSE),], 1, 
     function(x) c(rev(x[!is.na(x)]), x[is.na(x)])))
```

Comment: You are so fast to write down the `split` approach such that I have to find another way :)